# How can I create a video from a list of JPEG files?

Tags: c#, ffmpeg, video-capture

I did search and all I got is *Windows Media Encoder Series 9* and I am not sure if *DirectX* can also do it, but I can't find any way to learn it. I even tried [this tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8862/Capture-Activities-on-Screen-in-a-Movie) but I can' t run the application, it gives me a bug (I did install *Windows Media Encoder Series 9* and the SDK).

My application is now running JPEG files in a `PictureBox` with a timer, but the size of one minute is about 20 MB and that is not good. I need to save the whole day every day!

I found [this](http://download.cnet.com/Spy-Monitor-Screen-Recorder/3000-2162_4-75063923.html) software, it uses Windows Media Encoder and the video of one minute is about 1 MB which is great, now I know it's possible to record the desktop to a video file but how can I do it? I need a step by step explanation or videos to teach me.

Comment: why don't you use ffmpeg?

Comment: is there tutorial for it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tool [ffmpeg](http://www.ffmpeg.org) is perfect for doing this job. Their [documentation](http://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Video-and-Audio-file-format-conversion) has a example of the exact process you are trying to do.

> For creating a video from many images:
>
> ```
> ffmpeg -f image2 -i foo-%03d.jpeg -r 12 -s WxH foo.avi
> ```
>
> The syntax `foo-%03d.jpeg` specifies to use a decimal number composed of
>   three digits padded with zeroes to express the sequence number. It is
>   the same syntax supported by the C printf function, but only formats
>   accepting a normal integer are suitable.
>
> When importing an image sequence, -i also supports expanding
>   shell-like wildcard patterns (globbing) internally, by selecting the
>   image2-specific -pattern_type glob option.
>
> For example, for creating a video from filenames matching the glob
>   pattern `foo-*.jpeg`:
>
> ```
> ffmpeg -f image2 -pattern_type glob -i 'foo-*.jpeg' -r 12 -s WxH foo.avi
> ```

Just run this daily and it will convert your folder full of images in to a .avi file and you can delete the images when you are done.

Comment: nice but i need a step by step "i am nob"

Comment: Sounds like he's looking to record the desktop to a video file. The question title doesn't quite match the body. Look at the last paragraph - I might just be reading things wrong.

Comment: exactly @ErikNoren i need to record the desktop to a video file.

Comment: i like that @ScottChamberlain but i don't know what to type in my application?